# Drawing contours using cv2.approxPolyDP() in python

Tags: python, image, opencv, computer-vision, opencv3.0

I'm unable to draw complete contours of a shape using `cv2.approxPolyDP()`.

I'm getting the following result:

[image: My result]

But I want output like this:

[image: This is what I'm looking for]

Here's my code:

```
import cv2
im = cv2.imread('C:\Python27\Test\Targets\s1.jpg') # read picture

imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # BGR to grayscale

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

countours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

epsilon = 0.1 * cv2.arcLength(countours[0], True)
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(countours[0], epsilon, True)

cv2.drawContours(im, approx, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
cv2.imshow("Contour", im)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Hi, it's unclear what result you're getting, and what result you would like to see. Did you forget to embed the two images?

Comment: Did that. Now answer please

Comment: I tried out the same code. But I was able to obtain a contour around the rectangle

Comment: Like the one in the second image? @Jeru luke

Comment: @VikasTomar yes exactly

Comment: @VikasTomar see the answer section for the result I got

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE` removes all redundant points and compresses the contour, thereby saving memory. If you pass to `findContours()` function `cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE` parameter instead of `cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE`, your problem will be solved.
Your code should be changed as below:

```
_, countours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, 
                                                 cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

Answer (score 1):

it's quite long time ago, but I suggest you this way

```
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)

contours_sizes= [(cv2.contourArea(cnt), cnt) for cnt in contours]
biggest_contour = max(contours_sizes, key=lambda x: x[0])[1]

countours = biggest_contour
```

this will find biggest contour of the image, which ignores small dots and noise

Answer (score 0):

I tried out the same code. But I was able to obtain this:

[image]

Comment: Thats good. But is there a way I can obtain sharp and flat edges. I don't want those rough edges as I want to detect proper corners in shapes.

Comment: for straight lines you're gonna need something like HoughLines()

Answer (score 0):

In Java this works

```
MatOfPoint2f  newContour = new MatOfPoint2f();      
largestContour.convertTo(newContour, CvType.CV_32F);
double arcLength = Imgproc.arcLength(newContour, closed);
double epsilon = 0.2 * arcLength;
MatOfPoint2f approxCurve = new MatOfPoint2f();
Imgproc.approxPolyDP(newContour, approxCurve, epsilon, closed);

// convert back to form that can be plotted by drawContours
MatOfPoint largestOutline = new  MatOfPoint();
approxCurve.convertTo(largestOutline, CvType.CV_32S);
```